# How to fix "MissingBackpressureException"

Tags: java, rx-java, rx-java2

I am using RxJava2 Flowables by subscribing to a stream of events from a PublishSubject.It's being used in enterprise level application and we don't have the choice of dropping any events.
I am using version RxJava 2.2.8

I am using BackpressureStrategy.BUFFER as I don't want to lose any of my events.

Also, I buffer again for 50000 or 3 minutes whichever is earlier. This I do as I want to consolidate events and then process them.

But I get the following errors in a few minutes of my run

```
io.reactivex.exceptions.MissingBackpressureException: Could not emit buffer due to lack of requests
at io.reactivex.internal.subscribers.QueueDrainSubscriber.fastPathOrderedEmitMax(QueueDrainSubscriber.java:121)
at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableBufferTimed$BufferExactBoundedSubscriber.run(FlowableBufferTimed.java:569)
at io.reactivex.Scheduler$Worker$PeriodicTask.run(Scheduler.java:479)
at io.reactivex.internal.schedulers.ScheduledRunnable.run(ScheduledRunnable.java:66)
```

I tried increasing the buffer size by setting up, but there is no change in the behavior.

```
System.setProperty("rx2.buffer-size", "524288");
```

Also If I buffer for a longer time instead of 3 minutes, I get the exception after much longer time probably because my downstream performs better when the events are consolidated more. However, I don't have that choice because these are live events and needs processing immediately(in 3-5 minutes).

I also tried thread.sleep() before invoking the "subscription.next" in case of error but still getting the same results.

```
keySubject.hide()
.toFlowable(BackpressureStrategy.BUFFER)
.parallel()
.runOn(Schedulers.computation())
.map(e -> e.getContents())
.flatMap(s -> Flowable.fromIterable(s))
.sequential()
.buffer(3,TimeUnit.MINUTES,50000)
.subscribe(new Subscriber<List<String>>() {

@Override
  public void onSubscribe(Subscription var1) {
   innerSubscription = var1;
innerSubscription.request(1L);
 }

@Override
public void onNext(List<String> logs) {
    Subscription.request(1L);

///   Do some logic here

}
```

I want to know How do I handle the backpressure to avoid this exception? Is this exception because of ".buffer" method
Is there a way for me to check the status of these buffers. Also why even if I increase the rx2.buffer-size, I still get the exception in the same amount of time. Ideally, the system should run longer with a higher buffer size if the exception is because if buffer getting full.

Any help on the reason for this message "Could not emit buffer due to lack of requests at " will be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing is, why do you use a subject that isn't backpressure-aware? Are you using that as a poor man's event bus? Also, assuming `e.getContents()` is a simple getter I believe you can replace this whole block

```
.toFlowable(BackpressureStrategy.BUFFER)
.parallel()
.runOn(Schedulers.computation())
.map(e -> e.getContents())
.flatMap(s -> Flowable.fromIterable(s))
.sequential()
.buffer(3,TimeUnit.MINUTES,50000)
.subscribe(new Subscriber<List<String>>() { ... });
```

with

```
.flatMapIterable(e -> e.getContents())
.buffer(3,TimeUnit.MINUTES,50000)
.rebatchRequests(1)
.observeOn(Schedulers.computation())
.doOnNext(s -> /* Do some logic here */)
.subscribe();
```

Comment: Hi Tassos, 
Thanks a lot for looking into it.I am really excited about this suggestion and will try it out sometime soon. I have few queries on your response, request  you to clarify them.

1. Are you suggesting not to use flowable as I can not control my upstream?
2. I read about rebatchRequest(n), and it talks about 75 % of n in the subsequent request. but when you say rebatchRequest(1), what will be 75 % in that case. 
Or will it consider 75 % of our events in the buffer ( which is 50000, or 3 minutes)
3. Any specific reason for not overriding onError method.

Comment: 1. `rebatchRequests` will signal to upstream to send one element at a time. However, upstream of that is `buffer`, which means that the elements are collections of up to 50000 original elements. 

2. 75% in this case is 0; this means that it will request the next buffer of 50000 after it receives one.

3. This still means that your upstream is generating items faster than you can process them. Can you run parallel instances of the `Do some logic here` segment?